# How can i detect when the user presses slide to power off button in iphone ?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I need to send alert message to server from my app if the user presses slide to power off button in iPhone/iPad. how it can be done?  some help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. It isn't part of the public/documented APIs.